# Remove GIF image background to match Original background in GWT?

Tags: image, gwt, gif, image-formats

So I have an image (GIF) with a blueish background and a circle (which i want to keep), I would like to remove the blueish background and ( or show the origin color of the back ground it sites on or make the background of the image totally transparent. )

Thank you .

This is GWT 1.6

Answer (score 1):

GIF supports transparency also, open it in a image editor(not paint, it sucks) and select the background using the magic wand tool. Press delete and you're done!

PS: save it as GIF file if you have to..

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with GWT. The solution is to use PNG image format. PNGs allow you to specify a transparent background.